# Filtering ListFragment Through SearchView

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zn3m.png)I’m having trouble with making the listfragment searchable with Search Widget after filtering it through `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`.

**The code:::**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                hymns.HYMN_HEAD);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);

        mDuelPane = detailsFrame!= null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;


        if(savedInstanceState != null){

            mCurCheckPosition =  savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if(mDuelPane){
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        }

    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){ 

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 
            return true;
        } 

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query); return true;
        }
    }
```

The filter works but when the searched items are clicked, it will not return the index true position in the details activity. For instance, if an item is in 77th position in the original listview, and you try to search through by filtering, and after filtering, the said 77th item is now the number 1 position of the filters, when clicked, instead of returning the 77th position of the details activity, it returns the number one details of the original listview.
I hope you can help me with this as I’m a baby programmer. Thanks Sir

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TNkk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtNgK.png)

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @Munir I have edited the post to include the adapter code. Thanks

Comment: @pskink, i dont get your question. Did you mean i should try Adapter.getItem(int) ?

Comment: And where should I rightly add the code to? pardon my question @pskink

Comment: My code works but where i ahve a

Comment: My code works but where i have problem is, each of the item  in the listfragment has its relative details position corresponding to the item. when they are filtered in the searchview through adapter.getFilter. filter, the filtering works but when clicked, it doesnt return the right details for the item clicked. eg item no 20 could return the details of item no 1 in another activity when clicked

Comment: Since i'm using fragment onItemClickListener was not used but onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) was used intead

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your list with the new filtered adapter

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(query); 
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: do you pass the filtered list of strings to the adapter?